# Creating a wrapper for Google Play/Apple app

Tags: google-play

I have created an app using AppSheet and I am looking for information on how to create a wrapper that will turn my AppSheet into an app that can be purchased/downloaded in the Google Play or Apple stores. 
I have checked with AppSheet, they don't have anything in place at the moment to do this through them but they also said that there is nothing in their user agreement that prevents someone from doing what I am looking for. 
I'm just new to app development, I've done websites, just not apps and am looking for a little help.

Answer (score 0):

AppSheet now supports white-label apps. Please see [What is a White Label Native App?](https://help.appsheet.com/en/articles/962167-what-is-a-white-label-native-app)

Also, most support for AppSheet questions happens via http://community.appsheet.com so that's the best place to get questions answered.